# How to make HTTPS requests with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, https, progressive-web-apps

I've been working on a PWA game, and I've hit a little bit of a roadblock. I don't know how to make a HTTPS request with JavaScript. Of course, I did some googling, but didn't find anything. I'd use XMLHttpRequest(), however, PWA's need to be all HTTPS, because security reasons or whatever.

Im not using JQuery, Angular, Vue.js or any framework for that matter, and if possible, I'd rather avoid being tied down to a framework.

Any help/points in the right direction are appreciated :)

Comment: If you don't need to target older browsers, look at the Fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` works fine. The `https` part has to do with the URL you use.

Comment: As @Pointy said, what's wrong with an `XMLHttpRequest` to an HTTPS uri?

Comment: @Pointy so then my issue is that I'm using a http localhost (iirc, Googles own [PWA Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp), if not that then it was a W3 doc linked from there.) said that `http localhost is supported to facilitate testing`

Comment: I have no idea what that means. You can make `https://` requests with the normal `XMLHttpRequest()` facilitay and with `fetch()`. That's pretty much the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like @bruno-farina mentioned, look into `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`. Example:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Maybe you can't make the request because you are calling the target httpS URL from a non httpS location (calling https://target-url from http://localhost instead of https://localhost maybe?)

Comment: Its not that I can't make requests - I think its because i'm giving it a URL relative to the current page (by storing the URL to the current page as a string when the page loads), but I'm using http://localhost to test. So when I make the request, it invalidates the PWA (This is detectable by setting a chrome titlebar color, because if its invalid, it'll change back to white)
TLDR: I think the fact that localhost is a special case where http is allowed makes it have issues.